# Keyboard navigation for PySide GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I am using PySide for application development. Application is ready, but I want to use it using keyboard only. In short, when we press 'tab' key, it navigates various widgets sequentially & hitting 'enter', action is taken like 'mouse click'.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have thought PySide acted like this by default? Is that not the case?

Comment: nope. It's not like that atleast in my case.

Comment: @user2732017. In what way is it "not like that"? Are you claiming that tabbing doesn't move the focus at all?

Comment: Actually it is working with some widgets. But when tab enters in textedit widget, unable to get out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Some widgets can be set to interpret tab keys as input to the widget, rather than an instruction to change focus. One of these is `QTextEdit` in which the tab key can be set to enter tab characters in the text of the widget rather than changing focus.

You can stop this behavior by setting `my_text_edit.setTabChangesFocus(True)` for the appropriate `QTextEdit` widgets. You can alternatively set this behavior in Qt Designer if you are using that to generate the UI.

See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#tabChangesFocus-prop

I imagine there is a similar method call for any other widgets that are not interpreting the tab key as a command to change focus.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what three_pineaples suggests, if you don't want to lose the tab key functionality inside your focus grabbing widget (textedits, tables), you can always use labels with specific keyboard shortcuts to allow the user to focus away from a focus grabbing widget:

```
name = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
name_lbl = QtGui.QLabel('&Name:', self)
name_lbl.setBuddy(name)
```

makes Alt+n take focus to the 'name' widget, provided that the Alt+n accelerator is unique on the focused window.